# SELECT statements in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception

{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con =       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/convocation","root","");



int id_convo= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Insert Student ConvoID"));

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select name, course from stud_details where id='"+id_convo+"' ");

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while(result.next())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.getString(1) + " "+ result.getString(2));
}
}
}
```

Im having a problem with the statement where it only shows name and course. I dont know why for award it not showed. I already have it in the database and it only show the first two in the sql statement. Same if i do SELECET * . only the first two in the database will showed.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why award is not shown [sic].

Change your query from

```
select name, course
```

to

```
select name, course, award
```

and then

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.getString(1) + " "
    + result.getString(2));
```

to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.getString(1) + " "
    + result.getString(2) + " " + result.getString(3));
```

Also, as of JDBC 4.0 and Java 6 you shouldn't need to register your JDBC driver with

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

**Edit**

And, as noted in the comments, you really should use your `PreparedStatement` *correctly* by binding the parameter. Like,

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
    "select name, course from stud_details where id=?");
statement.setInt(1, id_convo);
```

Finally, don't forget to `close()` everything in a `finally` block.

Comment: And use a PreparedStatement

Comment: so . is it okay if i remove the newInstance() ? its works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already try wity SELECT *, it seen this problem is not in SELECT statement.
This problem is in this code

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.getString(1) + " "+ result.getString(2));.
```

If you understand result.getString() method, your problem will go away.
Try with below explanation:

```
result.getString(1) is represent first column of your table.
result.getString(2) is represent second column of your table.
result.getString(3) is represent third column of your table.
etc.........
........
........
```